# Nativescript: Strange error after app gets deployed

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I created a very basic Nativescript Android app that uses the nativescript-barcodescanner plugin.  The app builds successfully but when it gets deployed on the emulator I get the following error.  Any idea what I can do to resolve this or what could be causing this?

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.barcodescanner/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreateView failed

Error: File /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/.components/information/information.component.html does not exist. Resolved from: .components/information/information.component.html.
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js, line: 22, column: 12

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'FileSystemResourceLoader.get', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js', line: 22, column: 19
    Frame: function:'DirectiveNormalizer._fetch', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js', line: 13661, column: 45
    Frame: function:'DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/
```

And the last few lines of my command prompt:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 9.45 secs
Project successfully built
Successfully deployed on device with identifier '192.168.8.101:5555'.
W/System.err( 2258):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2258):    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:865)
W/System.err( 2258):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:730)
W/System.err( 2258):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:716)
W/System.err( 2258):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:697)
W/System.err( 2258):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:687)
```

Comment: It seems that it can not find `.components/information/information.component.html` and prevents from resuming  activity , maybe there is a problem with you relative path or something(like components instead of .components)

Comment: @HabibKazemi Thanks that helped a lot please add it as an answer.  It turned out to be a templateUrl in one of my components that was incorrect...

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it can not find `.components/information/information.component.html` and prevents from resuming
the activity , maybe there is a problem with you relative path or something(like components instead of .components)

Comment: Thanks again @HabibKazemi you solved two of my issues over the last day:)